# SQL Duplicate Entries (Having Blackout)

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm not that new to SQL but atm I got a blackout and whatever suggestion i try, wether here on SO or from anywhere else, I either mess it up or do not get any result.

I'll describe my situation.

My DB is called PCR

It has an RelationID which is the primary key in a GUID-form

Example: {4EB31301-FF42-4045-9A04-000490AF3C35}
It has a ConID and a ProID as GUID aswell and an INT.

RelationID is always different.

RelationID;  ConID;   ProID;   INT;

XYZ;          123;     456;     4;

XZY;           123;     456;     8;

YXZ;           123;     456;    16;

That's what it looks like for example.

Now I have to delete the row with the INT 8 and INT 16

I can not use the "DELETE XZY FROM  X WHERE D = Z" because I need to delete every row where ConID and ProID is the same in the row but i need to keep the row with the lowest INT.

EDIT: But there are other ProID's and ConID's with more than one entry and different INT's. These have to be deleted aswell except the one with the lowest INT.

I played around with Count and GROUP BY but I always messed up :/

Hope anyone can get me back on the road again.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

.c0dy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had similar problem a while ago.

```
; WITH cte AS (
    SELECT RelationID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ConID, ProID ORDER BY [INT]) AS rnum
    FROM YourTable
)
DELETE FROM YourTable 
WHERE RelationID in (SELECT RelationId FROM cte WHERE cte.rnum > 1)
```

Starting semicolon is needed for CTE.

Edit - corrected syntax error.

Comment: Looks like it has worked perfectly. I would have never come to that solution. Hehe Thank you VERY MUCH! Have a nice day :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful :) Cheers